# ObjectInputStream blocks forever during readObject()

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, encryption-symmetric, encryption-asymmetric

I'm trying to handle out a secured connection with a self made Server and client.
At first the client connects to the server and sends per ObjectOutputStream an PublicKey object to the server.
The server answers with an encrypted AES key, then both establish an AES encrypted input- and outputstream.

But the client keeps blocking during receiving the AES key.

Thats my client code:

```
private void createServerConnection(String serverAddress) throws IOException {
    connection = new Socket(serverAddress, 5555);
    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
    try {
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
        oos.writeObject(kp.getPublic());
        Cipher ci = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        ci.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, kp.getPrivate());
        byte[] aesKey = (byte[]) ois.readObject();
        aesKey = ci.doFinal(aesKey);
        SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(aesKey, 0, aesKey.length, "AES");

        Cipher aesCipherD = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        aesCipherD.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, originalKey);

        Cipher aesCipherE = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        aesCipherE.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, originalKey);

        this.oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new CipherOutputStream(os, aesCipherE));
        this.ois = new ObjectInputStream(new CipherInputStream(is, aesCipherD));

    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {

    } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {

    } catch(NoSuchPaddingException nspe) {

    } catch(InvalidKeyException ike) {

    } catch(IllegalBlockSizeException ibse) {

    } catch(BadPaddingException bpe) {

    }
}
```

And thats my server:

```
   public void run() {
    try {
        //Verbindung Aufbauen
        Socket s = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Eingehede Verbindung von " + s.getInetAddress().toString());
        new JSecSocket(server).start();
        OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
        InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
        System.out.println("Verbindung aufgebaut!");

        //PublicKey vom Client entgegennehmen
        System.out.println("Öffentlicher Schlüssel wird empfangen.");
        PublicKey clientPublicKey = (PublicKey) ois.readObject();

        //AES Key verschlüsseln und zum Client übertragen
        System.out.println("AES Schlüssel wird gesendet.");
        Cipher keyCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        keyCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, clientPublicKey);
        byte[] encryptetKey = keyCipher.doFinal(this.aesSk.getEncoded());
        oos.write(encryptetKey);

        System.out.println("Verschlüsselte Verbindung wird aufgebaut!");
        Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesSk);

        Cipher decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesSk);

        //Verschlüsselte Datenströme werden geöffnet
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new CipherOutputStream(os, encryptCipher));
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new CipherInputStream(is, decryptCipher));
        System.out.println("Verbindung bereit!");
        while (!this.isInterrupted()) {
            NetworkStatus ns = (NetworkStatus) ois.readObject();
            JSecDatabase database = new JSecDatabase("localhost", "root", "", "database");
            switch (ns.getAction()) {
                case "lookup":
                    System.out.println("Lookup von" + s.getInetAddress().toString());
                    String target = (String) ns.getValue();
                    try {
                        oos.writeObject(new NetworkStatus("lookupOk", database.lookup(target)));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        oos.writeObject(new NetworkStatus("lookupError", e));
                    }
                    break;
                case "create":
                    System.out.println("User wird erstellt von " + s.getInetAddress().toString());
                    oos.writeObject(new NetworkStatus("createOk", database.create()));
                    break;
                case "update":
                    System.out.println("User wird geupdated von" + s.getInetAddress().toString());
                    String[] updateTarget = (String[]) ns.getValue();
                    if (database.update(updateTarget[0], updateTarget[1], s.getInetAddress().toString())) {
                        oos.writeObject(new NetworkStatus("updateOk", s.getInetAddress().toString()));
                    } else {
                        oos.writeObject(new NetworkStatus("updateError", null));
                    }
                    break;
                case "delete":

                    break;
                default:
                case "close":
                    System.out.println("Verbindung zu " + s.getInetAddress().toString() + " wird getrennt!");
                    oos.close();
                    ois.close();
                    os.close();
                    is.close();
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("Es gab einen IO Error.\n" + ioe.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        System.err.println(cnfe.getMessage());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
        System.err.println(nsae.getMessage());
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException nspe) {
        System.err.println(nspe.getMessage());
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ike) {
        System.err.println(ike.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ibse) {
        System.err.println(ibse.getMessage());
    } catch (BadPaddingException bpe) {
        System.err.println(bpe.getMessage());
    }
    sockets.remove(this);
}}
```

I think its more a problem with the objectstreams, everytime i try to work with objectstreams on a socket i got similar problems.
Does someone had an idea whats there happening ?

Comment: Side note: do you know about the recently discovered Java bug with deserialization? Evil clients might be able to trick `readObject` into doing almost anything.

Comment: The readObject() method in the client application in line 13 is blocking.

Comment: What's the server doing when the client is waiting to read an object?

Comment: The server waits for an object send from the client to serve the client with the requested informations. That is happening in the while loop and the switch at the end.

Comment: Are objectstreams generally unrecomendet for client server applications or is there an way to make it more secure ?

Comment: You should flush() the output stream before reading from the input stream.

Comment: It's not blocking anymore but i got and EOF exception on the server by creating the second ObjectInputStream with the Cipher. Are there some limitations to open a new ObjectStream with and Stream that had an opend ObjectStream  before ?

Comment: java.io.EOFException
 ....
 at jsecserver.JSecSocket.run(JSecSocket.java:89)

Comment: Ok i was wrong. It still blocks, even when i'm flush() the ObjectOutputStream

Comment: The ObjectStream which receives the object, works in another application so why should they lock each other ?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. Checksum of what? It sends a *header*, but there's no checksum in it. There's nothing to checksum yet.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. Lock each other how? Clearly you haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use multiple streams over the same socket in general. There are specific cases where it works but in general you're up against unknown buffering which will get your peers out of sync quick as a wink. Redo it with a single `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`at each end. If you only need to encrypt certain parts of the stream, look into `SealedObject`.

Comment: I'm trying to use SealedObject instead, this seems intersting. After that i will answer if it also solves my problem with the blocking InputStream